# Como compruebo si un String contiene una cadena de texto?

Tags: java, netbeans

Una pregunta muy común en novatos como yo :)

> Quiero comparar si un string tiene una cadena de texto, ejemplo:
>
> ```
> String hola = "Hola"
> Hola.(MetodoQueCompara)("ol") = true
> ```
>
> El metodo includes() es solo para matrices, el equals es para saber si el
> string tiene una cadena de texto en especifico
> especifico, y yo quiero comparar solamente si tiene alguna letra de la
> que quiero comparar

Aqui les digo como :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer :

```
String myString = "soy una cadena";

if (myString.contains("soy"))  //validamos si myString contiene la subcadena "soy"
{
    //haces algo
}
else
{
    //sino hacemos otra cosa
}
```